# $.getJSON returns "undefined" values from github

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, undefined

I've just recently started getting into some ajax, and I'm trying to figure out how to pull data from a website using jsonp. I'm trying to pull the jQuery github account information and display it in the browser. The only problem being I keep receiving an undefined for the two values I am trying to pull out of each array in the json data. When I go to the console to error check, I can clearly see all of the json data file information.Another thing is that while there are many different entries, the `each` loop only does two iterations before it stops printing. My jQuery code is below.

```
var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/jquery/repos';
$('#letter-h a').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.getJSON(url + '?callback=?', function(data){
        var html = '';
        $.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry){
            html += '<div class="entry">';
            html += '<h3 class="term">' + entry.id + '</h3>';
            html += '<div class="part">' + entry.name + '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
        });
        $('#dictionary').html(html);
    });
});
```

I have looked through many different questions on this site (as this question apparently gets asked often) to try to assist but none of the suggestions have worked. This includes `entry[entryIndex].id`, `data.entry.id`, `data.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The github api seems to respond differently based on response type (JSONP vs JSON). For json, it responds `[...]`. For jsonp, it responds `{data:[...], meta:{...}}`.

I suggest just adding:

```
data = data.length ? data : data.data;
```

to the first line of your callback.

Comment: it worked! Thank you! So what you're checking for is if there is a length, then data remains; if not, add the data onto the end of it to test for api variability?